# Under what conditions can $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ be an inner product space for $p\neq 2$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

My measure theory book* claims that $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ is an inner product space only for $p=2$, where it is implied that the inner product induces the $p$-norm on $L^p$. I have seen proofs of this statement for specific $L^p$ spaces, like $\ell^p(\mathbb N)$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015212/prove-there-cannot-be-an-inner-product-which-turns-lp-into-an-inner-product-s)) and $L^p[0,1]$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997292/how-to-prove-that-lp-0-1-isnt-induced-by-an-inner-product-for-p-neq-2)).

However, I think this claim cannot be true in general, because of the following counterexample. Let $(X,\sigma)$ be any measurable space and let $\mu_0$ denote the trivial measure $\mu(A)=0$ for all $A\in\sigma$. Then $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ is the Banach space $\{0\}$, which is trivially an inner product space.

Are there any other examples where $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ is an inner product space (where the inner product induces the $p$-norm) with $p \neq 2$? If so, what are the strictest conditions on $(X,\sigma,\mu)$ under which $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ is an inner product space only for $p=2$ ?

---

*René Schilling, *Measures, Integrals, and Martingales* (2nd Edition), p. 326.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An inner product space (over $\mathbb R$) satisfies the parallelogram law
$$ \|x + y\|^2 + \|x - y\|^2 = 2 \|x\|^2 + 2 \|y\|^2$$

Another case where all $L^p$ are inner product spaces is where there is only one nonempty member $A$ of the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma$ such that $0 < \mu(A) <\infty$ (and thus $L^p(X,\sigma,\mu)$ is one-dimensional).

However, if there exist disjoint $A, B \in \sigma$ such that $0 < \mu(A), \mu(B) < \infty$, let $x$ and $y$ be the indicator functions of $A$ and $B$ respectively.  Then
$ \|x + y\|_p = \|x - y\|_p = (\mu(A) + \mu(B))^{1/p}$ while
$\|x\|_p = \mu(A)^{1/p}$ and $\|y\|_p = \mu(B)^{1/p}$.  The parallelogram law for $x$ and $y$ reduces to
$$ (\mu(A)+\mu(B))^{2/p} = \mu(A)^{2/p} + \mu(B)^{2/p} $$
which is true only if $p=2$: for $p > 2$ the function $f(t) = t^{2/p}$ is strictly subadditive on $(0,\infty)$, while for $p < 2$ it is strictly superadditive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just add that we can weaken the above to only having $A\neq B$ instead of $A$ and $B$ disjoint, since then $A\setminus B, B\setminus A\in\sigma$ are disjoint.

Comment: Not quite: for example, it could be that $\mu(A \backslash B) = 0$.  What is true is that if $0 < \mu(A), \mu(B) < \infty$ and $\mu(A \Delta B) \ne 0$ then at least two of $A \backslash B$, $B \backslash A$, $A \cap B$ are disjoint and have nonzero measure.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: How did you conclude that $L^p$ is one dimensional in that case?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani If $f \in L^p$ and $B$ is any Borel set bounded away from $0$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is either $\emptyset$ or $A$.  Show that $f$ is a constant times the indicator function of $A$..

Comment: Thank you. Is it also the case that if $\dim L^p > 1$, then one can find disjoint $A, B$ such that $0 < \mu(A), \mu(B) < \infty$?